# Android ndkBuild android_gradle_build missing for ABI

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, abi, ndk-build

I have an Ionic android project and I'm receiving

> platforms/android/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/debug/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json (No such file or directory)

When I run:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

That folder 'platforms/android/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/debug/' generated files for mips,mips64,x86 and x86_64

My build.gradle looks like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk{
          abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path '../../plugins/my-plugin/src/android/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ndk {
              abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        debug {
            ndk {
              abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
  compile ('org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1')
}
```

If I don't put the ABiFilters it just builds for x86 and mips. If I put it complaints about that file not being found

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to add some debug flags.

```
debuggable true
initWith debug
jniDebuggable true
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
      cFlags "-DDEBUG=1"
    }
}
```

My build.gradle now looks like
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk{
          abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path '../../plugins/my-plugin/src/android/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ndk {
              abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            initWith debug
            jniDebuggable true
            externalNativeBuild {
              ndkBuild {
                  cFlags "-DDEBUG=1"
                }
            }
            ndk {
              abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
  compile ('org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1')
}
```

Comment: It's a flippy problem for me, and changing build.gradle doesn't help. You also haven't explain what is responsible for it getting fixed. Doing `Build->Refresh linked C++ projects` seems to "fix" this, but I'll have to dig down to the root cause, as I need command-line build, and it has the same problem.

Comment: So this is an old bug and I don't have the exact environment here but for me adding the debug under buildTypes solved. What I would assume that some file on the debug part was needed . At the time I remember that it did not build ABI without the flag and started building with it